# Ionic factor of glucose?

Tags: solutions, covalent-compounds, boiling-point

I am trying to find the $K_\mathrm{b}$ for 50 g of glucose dissolved in 1 kg of ethanol, given the change in boiling point is $\pu{2.2 °C}$. The molality is therefore 0.278. But what is the ionic factor $(i)$? I was told it is the number of ions, so I tried 24, but the answer did not match up with the accepted value.

Comment: Glucose doesn't ionize when dissolved, so it would be 1. @VikramKaushik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more appropriate name for the ionic factor is the [van't Hoff factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_factor) of colligative properties. In the simplest terms, it is the number of particles created after being dissolved in the solution. Since glucose is *not* an ionic compound, it does not dissociate, therefore $i=1$ (meaning one glucose molecule stays one glucose molecule).